# Regex: match condition

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I want to match `foo` in `IF foo` where `foo` is dynamic and can have any format, so I need to match everything after `if` or `IF`.

I tried the following regexp:

```
((?!IF\s)|(?!if\s)).*
```

Which matches `F foo` and therefore not really what I want.

Comment: as per the regex tag: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Comment: What's wrong with: - `[Ii][Ff]\s(.*)`?

Comment: it matches all the input and not everything *except* "IF "

Comment: @user1882902.. I don't understand your comment. That regex I posted would match all the input in the form - `If|IF|iF|if anything`.

Comment: yes, but I'd like to match it without the IF and without the space inbetween. Otherwise you're obviously right if I wanted to match it with the IF..

Comment: But you can grab the second capturing group if you want the content of the `(.*)`. Is that not good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want positive lookahead, match everything following `IF`,`If`,`IF`,`iF` but not including:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=[Ii][Ff] ).*" <<< 'if match everything after'
match everything after

$ grep -Po "(?<=[Ii][Ff] ).*" <<< 'If match everything after'
match everything after

$ grep -Po "(?<=[Ii][Ff] ).*" <<< 'IF match everything after'
match everything after
```